# how do i get the value from the android listview?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi this is my code i want to access the `KEY_ID` that i put in maplist on list item click in a variable..
Please Help me How i can do this.

```
ArrayList (HashMap)  (String, String) mapList = new ArrayList(HashMap(String, String)) ();
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); 
// getting DOM element
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_Route);

    // looping through all song nodes <song>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_SchoolName, parser.getValue(e, KEY_SchoolName));
        map.put(KEY_ChildrenName, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ChildrenName));
        map.put(KEY_AlertTime, parser.getValue(e, KEY_AlertTime));
        map.put(KEY_RouteName, parser.getValue(e, KEY_RouteName));
        map.put(KEY_Notification, parser.getValue(e, KEY_Notification));
        map.put(KEY_StopName, parser.getValue(e, KEY_StopName));
        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        mapList.add(map);
    }

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, mapList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            int idw = position;
            long logss = id;

// There i want to access the KEY_ID..              

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **onItemClick** method, you need to fetch *HaspMap* out from *mapList* object from a specific *position*:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = mapList.get(position);

//and then read values out from 'map' object
```

Comment: but i have put the final before the maplist on the top.

Comment: it doesn't matter because you are reading values, not assigning to it

Answer (score 1):

USe this code to get the position of the selected listitem.

```
ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01); 

     lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

             Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);

        }
    });
```