# How to store value from OnItemClickListener in listview(Hashmap)?

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I want to store value `data1` when I click item on listview (Example I click position 0 store a , position 1 store b) I tried to learn [how do i get the value from the android listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088281/how-do-i-get-the-value-from-the-android-listview) but I can't to store value from this.

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
ListView list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

String[] data1 = { "a", "b" };
String[] data2 = { "1", "2" };

for (int i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Name", data1[i]);
    map.put("Datas", data2[i]);
    ArrList.add(map);
}

ListAdapter adapters = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, ArrList, R.layout.activity_column, new String[] { "Name", "Datas" }, new int[] {
            R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2 });
list1.setAdapter(adapters);

list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = ArrList.get(position);
        String result = map.toString();
    }
});
```

Comment: you must use `map.getValue()` or `map.getKey()` instead of  `map.toString();`

Answer (score 0):

Use keySet() for get all values from map

```
for (String key: map.keySet()) {

System.out.println("key : " + key)
System.out.println("value : " + map.get(key));
}
```

and To get the sepcific value.

```
 map.get(key);
```

but we can't get the hapmap using positon